# How to solve the URL decoding problem in Django and nginx

Tags: django, nginx, python-requests

My web app is deployed using nginx. I have view like below for the url /incoming/`.

```
def incoming_view(request):
    incoming = request.GET["incoming"]
    user = request.GET["user"]
    ...
```

When I hit my url `/incoming/?incoming=hello&user=nkishore` I am getting the response I need. but when I call this url using `requests` module with below code I am getting an error.

```
r = requests.get('http://localhost/incoming/?incoming=%s&user=%s'%("hello", "nkishore"))
print r.json()
```

I have checked the nginx logs and the request I got was `/incoming/?incoming=hiu0026user=nkishore` so in my view `request.GET["user"]` is failing to get `user`.

I am not getting what I am missing here, is it a problem with nginx or any other way to call in `requests`.

Comment: `user` is *not* a `User` object, it is just a vanilla `str`ing.

Comment: yeah it's just string I am trying to retrieve. If i hit the url `/incoming/?incoming=hello&user=nkishore` in my browser its working fine, problem with when I am calling using `requests`

Comment: What's this `hiu0026` in the log entry? And there's no `&` after `hiu0026` either. You should show us your actual code.

Comment: But is the port number correct? Shouldn't this be `localhost:8000`?

Comment: What is the error? Also at the end of `nkishore` you have `'` instead of `"`

Comment: that's what I am not getting @blhsing, in the nginx log it's showing requested url like that `/incoming/?incoming=hiu0026user=nkishore` it's not converting `u0026` to `&`

Answer (score 1):

See [Requests Docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) for how to pass parameters, e.g.

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)
>>> print(r.url)
https://httpbin.org/get?key2=value2&key1=value1
```

Internally, Requests will likely escape the `&` ampersand with `&amp;`. If you really want to do the URL manually, try as your URL string:

```
'http://localhost/incoming/?incoming=%s&amp;user=%s'
```